# How to retrieve external XML files into android application

Tags: android, xml

In my Android application, I want to retrieve an XML file from the internet and parse some tags in that file to my application. I got a working tutorial [here](http://www.anddev.org/using_xmlresourceparser_to_parse_custom_compiled_xml-t9313.html) which uses XMLResourceParser but that tutorial points out how to read an XML file from a local directory.

What are the method calls to retrieve an external XML file into my Android application?

```
XmlResourceParser xrp = this.getResources().getXml(R.xml.test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an InputStream to the XML file using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    InputStream xmlStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

    // Pass the xmlStream object to a XPP, SAX or DOM parser.
}
```

Comment: Hi I added a code snippet where i get the xml file and assigning it to XmlResourceParser. As your example mentioned, can I assign the InputStream object  to XmlResourceParser ??

Comment: You can. Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setInput(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

create a new folder "raw" in "res", put external xml in raw folder

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourXMLname);
```

Comment: No i want to load the XML from the Internet without downloading it

Answer (score 2):

If by "external XML file" you mean loading an XML file from the internet, check out [this article on HelloAndroid](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device) for how to download an URL to your device.

In terms of the actual XML parsing, I've found SJXP "Simple Java XML Parser" to be the simplest solution. It's lightweight, easy to use, and works using callback handlers. The website also has some sample code which is very helpful.
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/simple-java-xml-parser-sjxp/